# is it a graphic card probelm

Tags: graphics, nvidia

hi does anyone know why this happened
when I turn on my screen after it was off this happened

[image]

Comment: If your system is all good , then there is problem in video encoding decoding. Try a different Video or video player(VLC recommended)

Comment: tnx but actully i have this problem on discord too

Comment: Do you have an integrated Cpu? If yes then switch to it and try